# Melhorar a Cognição do gTTS

Tags: python-3.x

é possível melhorar a cognição do gTTS com Python?

Estou criando um projeto com enfase no "reconhecimento de voz" para comandos no PC // Arduino // Rasp // outros porém percebi que quando falo algo simples como apenas um "SIM" ele as vezes demora para dar um "stop" na captação... Segue as linhas de código que tenho do gTTS:

```
with SR.Microphone() as source:
    r   = SR.Recognizer()
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    os.system(beep)
    audio = r.listen(source)
os.system(boop)
with open(rec, 'wb') as song:
    song.write(audio.get_wav_data())
try:
    with open('/home/pi/bot/logs/yk12mmkiy78.db', 'a', errors = 'ignore') as datafile:
        datafile.write(r.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-BR") + ';')
```

Por enquanto ele está escrevendo o que foi dito num arquivo de texto chamado yk12mmkiy78.db e as vezes até palavras simples 
ele escreve errado é possível melhorar a cognição e o entendimento?

Answer (score -1):

Olá , tenho um pouco de experiência com TTS e ASR em sistemas Asterisk PBX , Amazon Poly e  Google TTs aqui na empresa, e o que fazemos para melhorar o entendimento e *timing* do processo é:

- Evitamos a 'fala aberta' , normalmente mapeamos as intenções com o [*Ngram*](https://pythonhosted.org/ngram/tutorial.html) para ficar mais assertivo a tomada de decisões para comandos e você configura a acurácia pois os TTS e ASRs de fato não são 100% eficientes.

Exemplo:
Palavra dita : 'Não' , o que a plataforma entende 'Pão'.

Se você configurar a acurácia em 80% por exemplo , a palavra "Pão" será aceita como "Não" dentro da intenção que você quer capturar do usuário.

- Ao invés de abrir o microfone direto , gravamos a fala do usuário e cortamos (em tempo de execução) caso fique muito tempo mudo (normalmente 2 segundos) antes de enviar o áudio para a plataforma transcrever (até para evitar custos).
- Acho que você já usa o google mas mesmo assim vou frisar pois pra nós fez uma grande diferença.  O reconhecimento de voz do google está muito mais evoluído para a fonética brasileira use -o.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Carlos desculpe a demora para dar uma resposta, não entendi muito bem o "-o" onde devo coloca-lo ?